# How to sort column in AG-Grid with empty Header Name

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to sort column in AG-Grid with empty Header?

colDef that is being passed:

```
var columnDefs = [{
    headerName: " ",
    sortable: true,
    suppressToolPanel: true,
    field: "  "
}];
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ujdHr9UlcOuP3mHw7uam?p=preview
First column's header name(Athlete) is marked empty string. On click on its header, it is not sorting that column.

I checked here but no where it is said if header name need not to be empty to enable sorting. : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

============================================================================

Updated Plunker after checking @UniCoder 's answer:
https://plnkr.co/edit/wQadPgAgBWeFbLc4MuKu?p=preview (specifically hidden header text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
*Keep headerName as "" and give  field: "name"*

```
var columnDefs = [{
          headerName: "",
          field: "name",
          width: 150,
          pinned: true
}]
```

**Solution 2:**
use **headerClass** as shown below and set that class opacity to 0.

```
var columnDefs = [{
     headerName: "header-name",
     sortable: true,
     suppressToolPanel: true,
     headerClass: 'hide-header',
     field: "  "
}];
```

//in css file

```
.hide-header{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[codepens link for working example](https://codepen.io/mukeshm280/pen/mNEKOK)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Solution 1 didn't work for me. Though Solution 2 worked. I will paste updated plunker with your suggestion so that whoever looking for answer can find quickly.

Comment: Neat idea, but it doesn't work for non-trivial cases.  Can you suggest the workaround when implementing `headerComponentParams` ?  In my case, I'm rendering an icon in the header.  Doing so, disables the sorting ability